# conditional statement formula's in Apache POI Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In Apache poi, can we use formula like this?

this is not working for me.

```
row.createCell(11).setCellFormula("SUM(D" + k + ",G" + k + ",J" + k + ")");     
row.createCell(12).setCellFormula("IF(L"+k+">=45.5,Maximum,IF(L"+k+">=40.5,Minimum))");
//run stops here
```

Is there any other way? i couldn't find

Comment: I think you are missing colon in the SUM formula ":". And in the IF condition formula, I think there are couple of things you need to check, (1) Text should be in double quotes like "Maximum" and "Minimum". You have missing quotes around this texts. (2) Why have you used + unnecessarily before Maximum and Minimum.

Comment: @PareshJ sorry for the delay. I change that to row.createCell(12).setCellFormula("IF(L"+k+" >= 45.5,Maximum,IF(L"+k+" >= 40.5,Minimum))");

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work? What errors do you get? from what? what else did you try? etc...

Comment: IF statements tend to return false only always on evaluation.